# How to iterate over a pipeline consisting of classes which executes a specific function and passes the result to the next class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipeline

Imagine we have a class which represents a pipeline. This pipeline is a list of objects which represents different operations. The first element of this pipeline get's its input parameter from the Pipe class. Afterwards, each objects output becomes the next object input parameter.

```
class Pipe():

    def build_pipeline(self):
        Stage1 = Object_X()
        Stage2 = Object_Y() 
        self.pipeline = [Stage1, Stage2]

    def run():
        for p in pipeline:
            # execute p's respective run()
            # pass this to the next element in pipeline      

class Object_X():
   # all kinds of definition

   def run()
       # do something

class Object_Y():
   # all kinds of definition

   def run()
       # do something
```

How would one tackle this challenge? Is there any pattern which I could use?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Im most simple case you could declare and reassign an input argument/parameter:

```
class Pipe():
    def build_pipeline(self):
        Stage1 = Object_X()
        Stage2 = Object_Y() 
        self.pipeline = [Stage1, Stage2]

    def run():
        input_arg = self.input_arg   # initial input from Pipe class
        for p in pipeline:
            input_arg = p.run(input_arg)
```